# A smart attack on SMTP evading fail2ban

Tags: linux, security, smtp, fail2ban, brute-force-attacks

I have an ongoing brute-force attack on my SMTP server in a way that evades typical fail2ban settings:

- attacks take place from several IPs in the same subnet
- a single IP attacks in intervals longer than an hour, apparently to evade being blocked by fail2ban that typically uses `findtime` and `bantime` shorter than an hour

This is the log:

```
2017-09-05 01:11:19 LOGIN authenticator failed for (User) [91.200.12.165]:57519 I=[192.168.1.224]:25: 535 Incorrect authentication data (set_id=soft)
2017-09-05 01:11:36 LOGIN authenticator failed for (User) [91.200.12.164]:51973 I=[192.168.1.224]:25: 535 Incorrect authentication data (set_id=sandy)
2017-09-05 01:15:22 LOGIN authenticator failed for (User) [91.200.12.121]:51545 I=[192.168.1.224]:25: 535 Incorrect authentication data (set_id=brown)
2017-09-05 01:28:57 LOGIN authenticator failed for (User) [91.200.12.105]:64938 I=[192.168.1.224]:25: 535 Incorrect authentication data (set_id=family)
2017-09-05 01:48:32 LOGIN authenticator failed for (User) [91.200.12.165]:64730 I=[192.168.1.224]:25: 535 Incorrect authentication data (set_id=soi)
2017-09-05 01:48:47 LOGIN authenticator failed for (User) [91.200.12.164]:59184 I=[192.168.1.224]:25: 535 Incorrect authentication data (set_id=sanjeev)
2017-09-05 01:50:13 LOGIN authenticator failed for (User) [91.200.12.166]:64999 I=[192.168.1.224]:25: 535 Incorrect authentication data (set_id=until)
2017-09-05 01:54:05 LOGIN authenticator failed for (User) [91.200.12.121]:58756 I=[192.168.1.224]:25: 535 Incorrect authentication data (set_id=bryan)
2017-09-05 02:04:34 LOGIN authenticator failed for (User) [91.200.12.105]:55772 I=[192.168.1.224]:25: 535 Incorrect authentication data (set_id=famous)
2017-09-05 02:25:36 LOGIN authenticator failed for (User) [91.200.12.165]:55563 I=[192.168.1.224]:25: 535 Incorrect authentication data (set_id=soldiers)
2017-09-05 02:25:48 LOGIN authenticator failed for (User) [91.200.12.164]:50017 I=[192.168.1.224]:25: 535 Incorrect authentication data (set_id=sanmiguel)
2017-09-05 02:30:33 LOGIN authenticator failed for (User) [91.200.12.166]:55835 I=[192.168.1.224]:25: 535 Incorrect authentication data (set_id=update)
2017-09-05 02:32:56 LOGIN authenticator failed for (User) [91.200.12.121]:49589 I=[192.168.1.224]:25: 535 Incorrect authentication data (set_id=bsd)
2017-09-05 02:40:11 LOGIN authenticator failed for (User) [91.200.12.105]:62983 I=[192.168.1.224]:25: 535 Incorrect authentication data (set_id=far)
2017-09-05 03:02:29 LOGIN authenticator failed for (User) [91.200.12.165]:62775 I=[192.168.1.224]:25: 535 Incorrect authentication data (set_id=solution)
2017-09-05 03:02:40 LOGIN authenticator failed for (User) [91.200.12.164]:57228 I=[192.168.1.224]:25: 535 Incorrect authentication data (set_id=santamaria)
2017-09-05 03:10:50 LOGIN authenticator failed for (User) [91.200.12.166]:63046 I=[192.168.1.224]:25: 535 Incorrect authentication data (set_id=upgrade)
2017-09-05 03:11:37 LOGIN authenticator failed for (User) [91.200.12.121]:56803 I=[192.168.1.224]:25: 535 Incorrect authentication data (set_id=bubba)
2017-09-05 03:15:41 LOGIN authenticator failed for (User) [91.200.12.105]:53820 I=[192.168.1.224]:25: 535 Incorrect authentication data (set_id=farias)
2017-09-05 03:39:36 LOGIN authenticator failed for (User) [91.200.12.165]:53612 I=[192.168.1.224]:25: 535 Incorrect authentication data (set_id=solve)
2017-09-05 03:39:48 LOGIN authenticator failed for (User) [91.200.12.164]:64441 I=[192.168.1.224]:25: 535 Incorrect authentication data (set_id=santos)
2017-09-05 03:50:50 LOGIN authenticator failed for (User) [91.200.12.121]:64015 I=[192.168.1.224]:25: 535 Incorrect authentication data (set_id=buchhaltung)
2017-09-05 03:51:30 LOGIN authenticator failed for (User) [91.200.12.166]:53880 I=[192.168.1.224]:25: 535 Incorrect authentication data (set_id=upload)
2017-09-05 03:51:34 LOGIN authenticator failed for (User) [91.200.12.105]:61032 I=[192.168.1.224]:25: 535 Incorrect authentication data (set_id=farm)
2017-09-05 04:17:31 LOGIN authenticator failed for (User) [91.200.12.165]:60825 I=[192.168.1.224]:25: 535 Incorrect authentication data (set_id=somebody)
2017-09-05 04:17:34 LOGIN authenticator failed for (User) [91.200.12.164]:55274 I=[192.168.1.224]:25: 535 Incorrect authentication data (set_id=sara)
2017-09-05 04:27:43 LOGIN authenticator failed for (User) [91.200.12.105]:51865 I=[192.168.1.224]:25: 535 Incorrect authentication data (set_id=farmer)
2017-09-05 04:30:06 LOGIN authenticator failed for (User) [91.200.12.121]:54848 I=[192.168.1.224]:25: 535 Incorrect authentication data (set_id=buddy)
2017-09-05 04:32:02 LOGIN authenticator failed for (User) [91.200.12.166]:61091 I=[192.168.1.224]:25: 535 Incorrect authentication data (set_id=upon)
2017-09-05 04:55:24 LOGIN authenticator failed for (User) [91.200.12.164]:62485 I=[192.168.1.224]:25: 535 Incorrect authentication data (set_id=sarah)
2017-09-05 04:55:24 LOGIN authenticator failed for (User) [91.200.12.165]:51657 I=[192.168.1.224]:25: 535 Incorrect authentication data (set_id=someone)
2017-09-05 05:03:42 LOGIN authenticator failed for (User) [91.200.12.105]:59078 I=[192.168.1.224]:25: 535 Incorrect authentication data (set_id=farmers)
2017-09-05 05:09:10 LOGIN authenticator failed for (User) [91.200.12.121]:62060 I=[192.168.1.224]:25: 535 Incorrect authentication data (set_id=build)
2017-09-05 05:12:27 LOGIN authenticator failed for (User) [91.200.12.166]:51923 I=[192.168.1.224]:25: 535 Incorrect authentication data (set_id=ups)
2017-09-05 05:33:26 LOGIN authenticator failed for (User) [91.200.12.164]:53321 I=[192.168.1.224]:25: 535 Incorrect authentication data (set_id=sat)
2017-09-05 05:33:26 LOGIN authenticator failed for (User) [91.200.12.165]:58869 I=[192.168.1.224]:25: 535 Incorrect authentication data (set_id=somethin)
2017-09-05 05:40:00 LOGIN authenticator failed for (User) [91.200.12.105]:49912 I=[192.168.1.224]:25: 535 Incorrect authentication data (set_id=fast)
2017-09-05 05:48:34 LOGIN authenticator failed for (User) [91.200.12.121]:52896 I=[192.168.1.224]:25: 535 Incorrect authentication data (set_id=building)
2017-09-05 05:53:00 LOGIN authenticator failed for (User) [91.200.12.166]:59136 I=[192.168.1.224]:25: 535 Incorrect authentication data (set_id=uranus)
2017-09-05 06:11:20 LOGIN authenticator failed for (User) [91.200.12.165]:49705 I=[192.168.1.224]:25: 535 Incorrect authentication data (set_id=son)
2017-09-05 06:11:21 LOGIN authenticator failed for (User) [91.200.12.164]:60535 I=[192.168.1.224]:25: 535 Incorrect authentication data (set_id=saturn)
2017-09-05 06:16:06 LOGIN authenticator failed for (User) [91.200.12.105]:57124 I=[192.168.1.224]:25: 535 Incorrect authentication data (set_id=father
```

Is there a way to make some sort of selective fail2ban setting that would catch such attacks in a way other than just increasing `findtime` and `bantime` to several hours?

Answer (score 1):

> Is there a way to make some sort of selective fail2ban setting that would catch such attacks in a way other than just increasing findtime and bantime to several hours?

You can create an additional rule with a regular expression only matching these clients, with higher findtime. Using an extra rule does not influence your other rules which work fine.

Comment: Considering that they try to brute-force guess password (via SMTP LOGIN), that might be harmful, yes.

Answer (score 0):

Be careful that you don't end up creating a rule that may get triggered by normal login failures. This depends on how many users you might have using the same ISP and, therefore, connecting from the same subnet, occasionally providing wrong credentials.

Fail2Ban is good for automating prevention of typical brute force attacks. This kind of malicious activities from a wider subnet are not so usual and are quite OK, probably even better, to be handled manually:

1. If you don't need authenticated SMTP from `91.200.12.0/22`, block it on your firewall.

   This might be easier if you had separate *submission* for authenticated SMTP on port `587` and never allow authentication on port `25`; that would prevent giving any information about SMTP logins on `25` and still allows possible legitimate incoming mail from `91.200.12.0/22`.
2. If you think this network is hijacked, the whois database has contact information. By contacting the owner of this IP block you may help them to solve the actual problem!

   ```
   inetnum:        91.200.12.0 - 91.200.15.255

   remarks:        **********************************Attention***************
   remarks:        The pool is used other Department!
   remarks:        In case of questions related to SPAM, HACKING, SECURITY
   remarks:        Please contact directly abuse@vhoster.net
   remarks:        tel: +38 (044) 379-28-50; +7 (499) 404-16-45
   remarks:        **********************************************************
   ```